# Where's the secret terminal on level 4?

Tags: superhot

I've found the secret terminals on the first three levels, but can't find it on level 4. I even went climbing around on the palm trees underneath the level, but still couldn't find it. Where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, naturally, I find it about 2 minutes after asking. I was so close!

So, here's how you get it.

1. Take out that initial guy in the back of the truck with you.
2. At this point, it's easiest to disarm but not kill the second guy, so no one will shoot at you.
3. Run forward (relative to the direction you start the map on, coming out of the truck) and jump up on some cars. You should come to a bottomless fall with a car floating in mid-air.
4. Jump on the car, then turn around so you're facing back the way you came.
5. Jump into the bottomless pit, but make sure you hold down the jump key so you float. Aim for the upside-down palm tree underneath the area you'd just been running across.
6. Once you land on the palm tree, break out the window of the phone booth. A gun would probably be handy here, but I did it by attacking it as I jumped from one palm tree to another.
7. Once the window is broken, jump into the phone booth. Face back towards the direction you started the map from, and you should see the terminal.